# Graphics.drawImage from another Thread does not draw anything in Java Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, image, swing, graphics

I'm trying to draw an animation in a `JPanel` by displaying all the frames as `BufferedImage` objects and using a `Thread` to invoke `g.drawImage` in the `JPanel`s `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method for each frame, with sleeping in between.  My understanding is that invoking `g.drawImage` from anywhere, as long as `g` is the `Graphics` object from the `paintComponent`, should cause the pixels in the `JPanel` to be updated, but there is no change in the `JPanel`.  Is that not how `Graphics.drawImage` works, or is it an issue with using another `Thread`, or something else all together?  An abbreviated version of my code is below, with unnecessary bits removed

```
class Example extends JPanel{

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        BufferedImage temp1;
        BufferedImage temp2;
        try{
            temp1 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\test1.png"));
            temp2 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\test2.png"));
        }catch(IOException e){
            temp1 = null;
            temp2 = null;
        }
        final BufferedImage image1 = temp1;
        final BufferedImage image2 = temp2;
        Thread drawThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                g.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, null);
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    // omitted
                }
                g.drawImage(image2, 0, 0, null);
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    // omitted
                }
            }
        });
        drawThread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new B());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
           }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current painting code is wrong. A painting method is for painting only. You would NEVER start a Thread from a painting method. You can't control when the painting method is invoked and every time the method is invoked you would start another Thread.

The Graphics object should only be used as a short duration object that exists for the duration of the painting method. You should not attempt to keep a reference to the object indefinitely.

> I'm trying to draw an animation

If you want to do animation then you use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the animation.

So you should have the image as a property of the class. Then when the `Timer` fires you change the image property and invoke `repaint()` on the panel.